# Transpose using AWK

Tags: unix, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transpose using AWK or Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659588/transpose-using-awk-or-perl)

Hi I would like to use AWK to get an output file in the format below. My input file is a space separated text file. Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks

Input File

```
id  quantity colour shape   size colour shape     size  colour  shape   size
1   10       blue   square  10   red    triangle   12   pink    circle  20
2   12       yellow pentagon 3   orange rectangle   4   purple   oval   6
```

Desired Output

```
id  colour  shape    size
1   blue    square   10
1   red     triangle 12
1   pink    circle   20
2   yellow  pentagon  3
2   orange  rectangle 4
2   purple  oval      6
```

Comment: Why was this question closed as a duplicate of a question that came after it. This question should be opened and the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659588/transpose-using-awk-or-perl question should be the duplicate. This is the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generalized so you can choose columns for output by name. I've tested it with additional columns in the input data and they don't get output regardless of their position.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    col_list = "colour shape size"
    # Use a B ("blank") to add spaces in the output before or
    # after a format string (e.g. %6dB), but generally use the numeric argument
    col_fmt = "%-12s %-14s %5d"
    # columns to be repeated on multiple lines may appear anywhere in
    # the input, but they will be output together at the beginning of the line
    repeat_fields["id"]
    # since these are individually set we won't use B
    repeat_fmt["id"] = "%4d "
    # additional fields to repeat on each line
    #repeat_fields["another"]
    #repeat_fmt["another"] = "%8s"
    ncols = split(col_list, cols)
    split(col_fmt, fmts)
    for (i = 1; i <= ncols; i++) {
        col_names[cols[i]]
        forms[cols[i]] = fmts[i]
    }
}

# save the positions of the columns using the header line
FNR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i in repeat_fields) {
            repeat[++nrepeats] = i
            repeat_look[i] = i
            rformats[i] = repeat_fmt[$i]
        }
        if ($i in col_names) {
            col_nums[++n] = i
            col_look[i] = i
            formats[i] = forms[$i]
        }
    }
    # print the header line
    for (i = 1; i <= nrepeats; i++) {
        f = rformats[repeat[i]]
        sub("d", "s", f)
        gsub("B", " ", f)
        printf f, $repeat[i]
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= ncols; i++) {
        f = formats[col_nums[i]]
        sub("d", "s", f)
        gsub("B", " ", f)
        printf f, $col_nums[i]
    }
    printf "\n"
    next
}

{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (i in repeat_look) {
            f = rformats[i]
            gsub("B", " ", f)
            repeat_out = repeat_out sprintf(f, $i)

        }
        if (i in col_look) {
            f = formats[i]
            gsub("B", " ", f)
            out = out sprintf(f, $i)
            coln++
        }
        if (coln == ncols) {
            print repeat_out out
            out = ""
            coln = 0
        }
    }
    repeat_out = ""
}
```

With this modified input data:

```
no id  colour base   shape    size colour shape     size  colour  shape   size material
14 1   blue   twenty square   10   red    triangle   12   pink    circle  20   wool
23 2   yellow ninety pentagon 3    orange rectangle   4   purple  oval    6    cotton
```

the output is:

```
  id colour      shape          size
   1 blue        square           10
   1 red         triangle         12
   1 pink        circle           20
   2 yellow      pentagon          3
   2 orange      rectangle         4
   2 purple      oval              6
```

Comment: This working. How do I increase the number of output columns from 3? Also how do I output to a text file?

Comment: @SantoshPillai: In the `BEGIN` block, just add more column names to `col_list` and corresponding format strings to `col_fmt`. If they're fields to be repeated on multiple lines like `id`, add more `repeat_fields` and `repeat_fmt` entries as I have done with the comment-out `another` field. The script takes care of the rest. To output to a text file, you can have the shell do it when you run the script: `./scriptname inputfile > outputfile` or you can add redirection inside the script by adding `> "outputfile"` at the end of every `print` and `printf` statement (but not `sprintf`).

Comment: Thanks. What's col_fmt = "%-12s %-14s %5d". Is it 12 string - 14 string and 5 decimal?

Comment: @SantoshPillai: Those are the `printf`/`sprintf` format strings for the columns listed in `col_list`. It allows you to set different widths and datatypes for each column. Yes, "s" is string, "d" is decimal (integer). The number is the field width. The hyphen makes the string left-aligned. See [`man 3 printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Comment: Thanks a million all working now. Great script

Comment: One last question I promise :). How do I used wild cards in col_list = "group_. state city" The . does not seem to work for group0, group1, group2...

Comment: I'm happy to help. There's no support in the script for wildcards. Could you just list them explicitly? How many like that are there? In order to support regexes (instead of wildcards), `if ($i in col_names) {` would have to be changed to a `for (j = 1; j <= ncols; j++)` loop that did `if ($i ~ col_names[j])` or something similar. Then you could have `col_list = "group[[:digit:]]+ state city"` for example. Thanks for accepting my answer. Don't forget that you can also upvote it.

Comment: I used a sed to change my group0,group1... to group. This has fixed the problem. It would have been good if I didn't have to specify the field widths for each columns. The output has variable spaces after data

Comment: @SantoshPillai: Change this line: `forms[cols[i]] = fmts[i]` to something like: `forms[cols[i]] = "%-14s"` to set fixed column widths for every column listed in `col_list`. You can change the column names without using `sed` by adding this line in the beginning of the `FNR == 1` block just below the first `for` line: `if ($i ~ /^group/) {$i = "group"}`

Comment: Sorry, I am still having problem with this. The script works great when I 2 fixed and 3 variable column. When I add a fourth column the output gets messed up. Is there anyway I could send you a sample input data?

Comment: @SantoshPillai: You can post it to a pastebin site such as [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com). Be sure to post any code modifications you've made also.

Comment: Data
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0rMch-nfpzmSE5pWnhWbDVnOWM

Code
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0rMch-nfpzmRW5Sbk1JRDBKUW8

If I remove dchno_0 in the code the script works correctly

Comment: @SantoshPillai: I apologize, but it might be about two hours before I can take a look at your files. How many fields per line?

Comment: 88 fields per line. Everything after field ch_group till the next repetition of fields occur

Comment: @SantoshPillai: How is it messed up? It seems to work fine for me. I widened the `SITE` field to 18 characters and the alignment was better, but that's just a minor adjustment.

Comment: @SantoshPillai: Oh, now I think I see what's wrong. Let me see what I need to do to fix it.

Comment: @SantoshPillai: It seems that your data has different numbers of fields on each line: 4043, 4022, 4025, 4022, 4028, 4029, 4026, 4011, 4021, 4013, 4016, 4024, 4019, 4024. Is the data delimited by sequences of spaces or by tabs? The data file you uploaded appears to be space delimited. It seems the missing fields may be after the first three you've chosen, but before the last one so the problem only shows up when you add the last one.

Comment: the fields with userdata is sometimes blanks so this is causing the difference in the number of fields. There is a corresponding space/tab in the data where this is blank. The file opens up correctly in excel with tab delimiter. Is there any way to get around this in your code?

Comment: could you please answer this too?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659588/transpose-using-awk-or-perl

Answer (score 1):

see below:

```
kent$  cat a
id  colour  shape   size colour shape     size  colour  shape   size
1   blue    square  10   red    triangle   12   pink    circle  20
2   yellow  pentagon 3   orange rectangle   4   purple   oval   6

kent$  awk 'NR==1{print "id colour shape size";next;}
{id=$1; printf id;
        for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
                printf FS$i; if((i-1)%3==0)printf (NF!=i)?"\n"id:"\n"; }}' a         
id colour shape size
1 blue square 10
1 red triangle 12
1 pink circle 20
2 yellow pentagon 3
2 orange rectangle 4
2 purple oval 6
```

if you have 'column', you can pipe the output to column to make it look better:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==1{print "id colour shape size";next;}
{id=$1; printf id;
        for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
                printf FS$i; if((i-1)%3==0)printf (NF!=i)?"\n"id:"\n"; }}' a|column -t
id  colour  shape      size
1   blue    square     10
1   red     triangle   12
1   pink    circle     20
2   yellow  pentagon   3
2   orange  rectangle  4
2   purple  oval       6
```

Comment: I am seeing the error     awk: script.awk
awk:       ^ syntax error
errcount: 1    I am running the script by command: awk script.awk data.txt  . My data also contains other columns before and after the ones I want to extract

Comment: You could use `column` or you could use format specifiers with your `printf` statements.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

Content of `script.awk`:

```
FNR == 1 { 
    for ( i = 1; i <= 4; i++ ) { 
        header = (header ? header "\t" : "") $i
    }   
    printf "%s\n", header
    next
}

FNR > 1 { 
    id = $1
    for ( i = 2; i <= NF; i += 3 ) { 
        j = i + 2 
        for ( ; j >= i; j-- ) { 
            line = $j "\t" line
        }   
        printf "%d\t%s\n", id, line
        line = ""
    }   
}
```

Run it like (thanks to *Kent* for `columnt -t` command):

```
awk -f script.awk infile | column -t
```

With following output:

```
id  colour  shape      size
1   blue    square     10
1   red     triangle   12
1   pink    circle     20
2   yellow  pentagon   3
2   orange  rectangle  4
2   purple  oval       6
```

Comment: should I insert my header rows here (what's the ?):header = (header ? header "\t" : "") $i

Comment: @SantoshPillai: That instruction appends first four fields separated with tabs (`$1`, `$2`, `$3` and `$4`). `(header ? header "\t" : "")` is the same as an `if` instruction to avoid inserting a tab just before the first field: `if ( header ) { header = header "\t" } else { header = $i }`

Comment: My data also contains other columns before and after the ones I want to extract. I would prefer to reference the columns by header names (if the columns positions changes then this would not work). Is it possible to do this using your script?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '1! {s/\([0-9][0-9]*\)[ \t][ \t]*/\1\n/g;}' test.txt |awk -vOFS="\t" 'NR==1 {print $1,$2,$3,$4} NF==1 {id=$1} NR>1 && NF>1 {print id,$0}'
```

Tried to do it all in sed, but I am to green with the hold buffers and what not. Anyhow, insert a line break after each number:

```
id  colour  shape   size colour shape     size  colour  shape   size
1
blue    square  10
red    triangle   12
pink    circle  20
2
yellow  pentagon 3
orange rectangle   4
purple   oval   6
```

and use awk to shift down the id to the following rows:

```
id  colour  shape   size
1   blue    square  10
1   red    triangle   12
1   pink    circle  20
2   yellow  pentagon 3
2   orange rectangle   4
2   purple   oval   6
```

Should be doable completely in sed though