# Transpose using AWK or Perl

Tags: perl, unix, awk

Hi I would like to use AWK or Perl to get an output file in the format below. My input file is a space separated text file. This is similar to an earlier question of mine, but in this case the input and output has no formatting. My column positions may change so would appreciate a technique which does not reference column number

Input File

```
id quantity colour shape size colour shape size colour shape size
1 10 blue square 10 red triangle 12 pink circle 20
2 12 yellow pentagon 3 orange rectangle 4 purple oval 6
```

Desired Output

```
id colour shape size
1 blue square 10
1 red triangle 12
1 pink circle 20
2 yellow pentagon 3
2 orange rectangle 4
2 purple oval 6
```

I am using this code by Dennis Williamson. Only problem is the output I get has no space separation in the transposed fields. I require one space separation

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
col_list = "quantity colour shape"
# Use a B ("blank") to add spaces in the output before or
# after a format string (e.g. %6dB), but generally use the numeric argument

# columns to be repeated on multiple lines may appear anywhere in
# the input, but they will be output together at the beginning of the line
repeat_fields["id"]
# since these are individually set we won't use B
repeat_fmt["id"] = "%-1s "
# additional fields to repeat on each line

ncols = split(col_list, cols)

for (i = 1; i <= ncols; i++) {
    col_names[cols[i]]
    forms[cols[i]] = "%-1s"
}
}


# save the positions of the columns using the header line
FNR == 1 {
for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    if ($i in repeat_fields) {
        repeat[++nrepeats] = i
        repeat_look[i] = i
        rformats[i] = repeat_fmt[$i]
    }
    if ($i in col_names) {
        col_nums[++n] = i
        col_look[i] = i
        formats[i] = forms[$i]
    }
}
# print the header line
for (i = 1; i <= nrepeats; i++) {
    f = rformats[repeat[i]]
    sub("d", "s", f)
    gsub("B", " ", f)
    printf f, $repeat[i]
}
for (i = 1; i <= ncols; i++) {
    f = formats[col_nums[i]]
    sub("d", "s", f)
    gsub("B", " ", f)
    printf f, $col_nums[i]
}
printf "\n"
next
}

{
for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    if (i in repeat_look) {
        f = rformats[i]
        gsub("B", " ", f)
        repeat_out = repeat_out sprintf(f, $i)

    }
    if (i in col_look) {
        f = formats[i]
        gsub("B", " ", f)
        out = out sprintf(f, $i)
        coln++
    }
    if (coln == ncols) {
        print repeat_out out
        out = ""
        coln = 0
    }
}
repeat_out = ""
}
```

Output

```
id quantitycolourshape
1 10bluesquare
1 redtrianglepink
2 circle12yellow
2 pentagonorangerectangle
```

My apologies for not including all info about the actual file earlier. I did this only for simplicity, but it did not capture all my requirements.

In my actual file I am looking to transpose fields n_cell and n_bsc for NODE SITE CHILD

```
NODE SITE CHILD n_cell n_bsc
```

[Here is a link to the actual file I am working on](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0rMch-nfpzmbU1zRVluTzBpdFU)

Comment: The name of the language is "Perl", not "PERL".

Comment: However it is "AWK". My answer to this question would be identical to [my answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11454983/26428).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transpose using AWK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447885/transpose-using-awk)

Comment: I have flagged the previous one for deletion

Comment: What does your *real* file look like? You didn't like solutions for this specific format and you pass information drip by drip, like that there are more than 5,000 columns. Are the first two columns always `id` and `quantity`? Are the remaining columns always `colour`, `shape` and `size`? Is the information always in sets of three columns? Anything else we should know?

Comment: I would have like to include a sample of my actual input, but would be difficult to include it here since there are so many columns. The first two columns in my actual data are not id and quantity, they appear in 8th and 9th columns. This is why I would like the code to refer to column header names instead of column ids. I will post a like to my actual file

Comment: Then my solution may work for you, but there are still many things that could go wrong. Use [`pastebin`](http://pastebin.com) to publish large or awkward data.

Comment: OK so you want *only* those five columns? There is a `SITE` column in your data but no `NODE` or `CHILD`. And the eighth and ninth columns are `CELL` and `acc_0`, not `id` and `quantity`

Answer (score 3):

```
<>;
print("id colour shape size\n");

while (<>) {
   my @combined_fields = split;
   my $id = shift(@combined_fields);
   while (@combined_fields) {
       my @fields = ( $id, splice(@combined_fields, 0, 3) );
       print(join(' ', @fields), "\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: `perl script.pl infile >outfile` Or in-place: `perl -i script.pl file`

Comment: My actual input file has over 5k columns, so would like to refer the fixed columns and columns to transpose using header rows instead of column ids

Comment: @Santosh Pillai, Are they always in the same order? It would be more useful to know the number of columns, if so. Then just change `3` to that number in my code. If they're not always in the same order, how can you tell which column belongs to which row?

Answer (score 0):

You have told us that your real data consists of over 5,000 columns and that its column positions may change and I'm afraid that really isn't enough.

So in the absence of any proper information I have written this, which uses the header line to calculate the number and size of the sets of data, where the `id` column is, and in which column the first set starts.

It works fine on your example data, but I can only guess whether it will work on your live file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @headers = split ' ', <>;

my %headers;
$headers{$_}++ for @headers;

die "Expected exactly one 'id' column" unless $headers{id} // 0 == 1;
my $id_index = 0;
$id_index++ while $headers[$id_index] ne 'id';

my @labels = grep $headers{$_} > 1, keys %headers;
my $set_size = @labels;
my $num_sets = $headers{$labels[0]};

my $start_index = 0;
$start_index++ while $headers[$start_index] ne $labels[0];

my @reformat;

while (<>) {
  my @fields = split;
  next unless @fields;
  my $id = $fields[$id_index];
  for (my $i = $start_index; $i < @fields; $i+=$set_size) {
    push @reformat, [ $id, @fields[$i..$i + $set_size - 1] ];
  }
}

unshift @labels, 'id';
print "@labels\n";
print "@$_\n" for @reformat;
```

**output**

```
id colour shape size
1 blue square 10
1 red triangle 12
1 pink circle 20
2 yellow pentagon 3
2 orange rectangle 4
2 purple oval 6
```