# transpose a column in unix

Tags: unix, awk, transpose

I have a Unix file which has data like this.

```
1379545632,   
1051908588,    
229102020,    
1202084378,    
1102083491,    
1882950083,    
152212030,    
1764071734,    
1371766009,
```

(FYI, there is no empty line between two numbers as you see above. Its just because of the editor here. Its just a column with all numbers one below other)

I want to transpose it and print as a single line.

Like this:

```
 1379545632,1051908588,229102020,1202084378,1102083491,1882950083,152212030,1764071734,1371766009
```

Also remove the last comma.

Can someone help? I need a shell/awk solution.

Comment: You just need to use the editors `{}` button to correctly format the sample input/output in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose using AWK or Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659588/transpose-using-awk-or-perl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ printf 'x,\ny,\nz,\n' | awk -v RS='^$' '{gsub(/\n|(,\n$)/,"")} 1'
x,y,z
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file.txt
```

To remove the last comma you can try `sed 's/,$//'`.

Comment: Once you remove all the newlines the output is no longer a POSIX text file so YMMV wrt what any UNIX tool you pipe it to, including sed, does with it.

Comment: Nice!  And you can use `cut` to extract a particular column from grep output for example and pipe into this.  `grep -i 'create\sview' someddl.sql | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | tr '\n' '|'`.  This got a me a list of all the views which I can then use as a pattern to another grep to see who uses them.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS="" } { print }' file
```

ORS : Output Record separator.
Each Record will be separated with this delimiter.